# How to Link the title

Tags: php, html

How can i link the title in this code.

```
 echo "<div id='vblock'>";
      echo "<div style='width:130px;height:95px;float:left'>";
            echo '<a class="bloc_ca" href="'.$video['video_id'].'_'.str_replace(" ","-",substr(html_entity_decode($video['video_title']),0,20)).'.html"><img src="'.$thumb.'" alt="'.$vtit.'" width="120" height="90"></a></div>';
    echo "<div class='cvtitle'>
        <div><b>".html_entity_decode(substr($video['video_title'],0,100))."..</b></div>
        <div class='cvdisc'><span style='word-break:wrap'>".html_entity_decode(substr($video['video_desc'],0,100))."</span></div>
        <div class='cvviews'> View Count: <b>".$video['views']."</b></div></div></div>";
```

this is another code linked. its working

```
echo '<a class="a_bloc" href="'.$video['video_id'].'_'.str_replace(" ","-",substr(html_entity_decode($video['video_title']),0,20)).'.html">
                <div class="bloc">
                <img src="'.$thumb.'" alt="'.$vtit.'" height="60" width="80">
                <div class="txt">'.$video['video_title'].'</div>
                </div></a>';
    }
    ?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use an `<a>` tag.  Is this your question?

Comment: ya can u tell me how to use a `<a>` tag in the 1st code in title. title code is `.html_entity_decode(substr($video['video_title'],0,100))."..`

Comment: what are you asking?  Literally how to use an anchor tag?  You have already done it in other parts of your code...  I don't follow what your question is.

Comment: ? Why are using html_entity_decode() to change the representation of as string you are putting INTO html!!!!! That should be htmlentities(...)!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "<div id='vblock'>";
echo "<div style='width:130px;height:95px;float:left'>";
echo '<a class="bloc_ca" href="'.$video['video_id'].'_'.str_replace(" ","-",substr(html_entity_decode($video['video_title']),0,20)).'.html"><img src="'.$thumb.'" alt="'.$vtit.'" width="120" height="90"></a></div>';
echo "<div class='cvtitle'><div><a class="bloc_ca" href="'.$video['video_id'].'_'.str_replace(" ","-",substr(html_entity_decode($video['video_title']),0,20)).'.html"><b>".html_entity_decode(substr($video['video_title'],0,100))."..</b></a></div><div class='cvdisc'><span style='word-break:wrap'>".html_entity_decode(substr($video['video_desc'],0,100))."</span></div><div class='cvviews'> View Count: <b>".$video['views']."</b></div></div></div>";
```

It aint pretty though.  All you need to do is wrap the anchor:

```
<a class="bloc_ca" href="'.$video['video_id'].'_'.str_replace(" ","-",substr(html_entity_decode($video['video_title']),0,20)).'.html">YOUR LINK TEXT</a>
```

Around the title in the string.  Because you are reusing the anchor href and it's quite a long one I would favour setting a variable to the href value then using the variable for clarity.

Comment: i try this code but here in a class="bloc_ca" is acting as a code. if you put in Dreamweaver you will see "bloc_ca is highlighted in black

Comment: Did you use single quotes in the echo statement?